# Log Analytics Workspace KQL Queriy how can i split report whne it is more than 30k records(w/o using API)

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

Hello i have a problem with spliting reports in KQL in azure portal.
What is workaround when results are more than 30k and i want to split it and make sure im not missing any logs?
Time value it's not good solution because sometime there is a situation where logs are almost from the same time at once.

Answer (score 0):

**30K** is the limitation for the **Azure portal**

[image: Azure portal]

The limitation for the **Query API** is **500K**

[image: Query API]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits#log-analytics-workspaces

Comment: yes yes i understand that, but im not asking about limitation i', asking what if i have let's say 300k logs from one day and i want to generate it on azure portal(api is not accessible for me now) is there any way to split it somehow?

Comment: If API was an option, like this post header suggests, then you should have been aware that the limitation for API is far higher than the 30K limitation in the portal. If the API is not an option, you should change the header of your post.

Comment: but in header you have w/o without using API

Comment: I thought W/O stands for With/Out = With/Without. I guess I was wrong.